# How to remove focus from an editText on click any other portion of the screen

Tags: android

I have two EditText views on my page. I want to rid them of the focus when I am not clicking on them. I can't get it to work. I tried this. I set this method to each view except EditTextView But this gets rid of only the cursor and the keyboard The view is still highlighted. Is there any lighter way to do this.  Any suggestions.

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
            (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    EditText editText = (EditText) (activity.getCurrentFocus());
    editText.setCursorVisible(false);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: So the purpose is hidding softkeyboard? or you just want to rid out of focus this

Comment: I want that whenever i click the empty space on the screen, the cursor should go, the color of the underline color should return to default  and the keyboard should be invisible. I am able to achieve first and last but can't figure out the middle one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AtifAbbAsi, thanks for the answer.This is how I fixed it.

```
rootView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(getCurrentFocus() instanceof EditText){
        EditText editText = (EditText) getCurrentFocus();
        hideKeyboard(LoginActivity.this);
        editText.clearFocus();
    }
    return false;
}
});
```

this is the code i modified for hideKeyboard function

```
    public void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
            (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(
                    Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if(getCurrentFocus() instanceof EditText){
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can add true and false depends on you want to consume this click or not.

Comment: can you point me to a link or explain it yourself what consuming a click means?

Comment: touch listener is set to rootview now. so true means we want this click . false means pass it to other view. if you are still confused you can check android offical documentation.

Answer (score 1):

try removing focus, simply add touch listener it will detect intraction on screen and will remove focus.

```
    rootView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){

            }else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){


            }
        editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        editText.setFocusable(false);
        editText.clearFocus();

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Adding this does help me get the desired output, but i am confused about the utility of the if else if part as they are doing nothing. Also please explain the reason for return true at the end

Comment: action move means when you click on screen and action up means when you lift your finger up. and there is one more action down you can add logs to.it and check which one will help you.